# OnGesturePan not working

Tags: c++, mfc, touch, gestures

I am trying to add touchpad gesture support to an existing MFC application.  I'm using VS 2010, with the new MFC which supports OnGestureZoom and OnGesturePan(), however, I can't make these work.  I have breakpoints in them, but they are never called.

I have a touchpad on my laptop, and it is working with the default windows processing (i.e. zoom comes through as a mouse scroll wheel event).  However, I want to override this zoom behaviour and also process panning, rotation, etc.

In OnCreate(), I am calling

```
int lval = GetSystemMetrics(SM_DIGITIZER);
int ltouches = GetSystemMetrics(SM_MAXIMUMTOUCHES);
```

and both functions return zero, so this indicates that there is some other problem here that is stopping gestures from working correctly

I have also tried calling RegisterTouchWindow() in OnCreate, but this makes no difference.

Edit to add - I've tried following this simple tutorial [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7trainingcourse_win7multitouchgesturemfc_topic2.aspx][1], but still no joy.  At Task 2, step 4, my application simply says that "No touch input is currently available."

Comment: `RegisterTouchWindow` tells the system that you want to handle raw `WM_TOUCH` messages. Do not call `RegisterTouchWindow` if you want the system to process input and generate `WM_GESTURE` for you.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought RegisterTouchWindow did, but I put it in for a test just in case.  Apart from that one test, I am normally running without calling RegisterTouchWindow().  :)

Answer (score 0):

What O/S are you running on?

Also check if the `Tablet PC Input` service is started -- the [GetSystemMetrics function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `SM_DIGITIZER` says "*Nonzero if the current operating system is Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 and the Tablet PC Input service is started*".

Comment: Running on Windows 8.  It's not a tablet PC though.  I don't have a tablet PC input service.

Comment: I'm a bit confused -- you say that the two `GetSystemMetrics()` functions are returning zero, but also "I have a touchpad on my laptop, and it is working with the default windows processing" -- does this mean that other applications respond to touch (like pinch-and-zoom)?

Comment: Correct.  Other applications are responding correctly to touch with pinch and zoom and two-finger panning.  My app even responds to the default processing, where pinch-zooming is translated into mouse wheel events, and two-finger vertical panning is also translated into mouse-wheel events.  But I want to override this and put in my own improved handling for two-finger panning, etc.

Comment: Hmmm... which class are you overriding for your `OnGestureZoom()`? We process the gesture messages in our WindowProc itself -- could you see if your WindowProc receives the `WM_GESTURE` message?

Comment: I've tried deriving from CWnd or CView.  Same result - GetSystemMetrics reports zero, and I'm not receiving any WM_GESTURE messages.  (Not calling RegisterTouchWindow(), so that's not the issue either)

Comment: See if you get a [WM_GESTURENOTIFY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd353243(v=vs.85).aspx) message in your WindowProc and call [SetGestureConfig()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd353241(v=vs.85).aspx) -- sorry, can't think of anything else!

Comment: No WM_GESTURENOTIFY messages either.  GetGestureConfig() shows that pan/zoom are already enabled.  Used SetGestureConfig() just to make sure.  No difference!